# Unable to remove memcache with php? But able to with telnet

Tags: php, memcached, telnet

I was able to remove memcache with telnet but not php. What could be the reason for this?

**Telnet Code : (WORKING)**

telnet localhost 12345

Delete "Key"

^]

quit

**PHP code: (NOT WORKING)**

$memcache = new Memcache;

$memcache->connect('localhost', 12345)

$memcache->delete("key");

Comment: i think its `Key` in PHP?

Comment: Hi @IftekharDani . What do you mean?

Comment: in talent, you use `Key` with capital `K` and in PHP you use small `key` So, iguess you miss this

Comment: IftekharDani the "key" is suppose to be the session_id() but i did that to show that is where the memcache key suppose to be. :)

Comment: can you please refer : `http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.delete.php`

Comment: look like you also not create proper object `$memcache = new Memcache` should be $memcache = new Memcache();

Comment: @IftekharDani I already did long time ago. But thanks

Comment: I tried that too Memcache()